# How do I show the full path to the executable that "/usr/bin/env bash" is using?

Tags: unix

e.g.,
`/usr/bin/env bash` -- what is the path to the `bash` that it executes?

I tried `env -vvvvvvv bash` but it doesn't show me:

```
$ env -vvvvvv bash
#env verbosity now at 2
#env verbosity now at 3
#env verbosity now at 4
#env verbosity now at 5
#env verbosity now at 6
#env verbosity now at 7
#env verbosity now at 8
#env executing: bash
#env    arg[0]= 'bash'
```

Comment: It's doing a $PATH search for bash, so I assume it would be the same as `which bash`.

Comment: BTW, this isn't a bash question; `env` behaves the same way no matter which executable you tell it to invoke; there's no special-case behavior for bash.

Comment: BTW, the POSIX-standardized alternative to `which bash` is `command -v bash`.

Comment: (also, if you want to see what's actually being called definitively, `strace` will do that for you).

Comment: > BTW, this isn't a bash question; env behaves the same way no matter which executable you tell it to invoke; there's no special-case behavior for bash. – 

Yes, I struggled to find an appropriate tag.

Comment: > (also, if you want to see what's actually being called definitively, strace will do that for you).

Unfortunately I'm running on MacOS, so "strace" isn't available.  :-(

Comment: For future note, I'd use the [tag:unix] tag for questions about behavior of POSIX-standardized tools. (And as an aside re: strace alternatives, MacOS has `truss` in old versions and `dtruss` in new versions, but it's harder to use in recent years than it used to be on account of locked-down security)